# LWJGL Collision Detection flaw

Tags: java, collision-detection, lwjgl

I am currently using this code for 2D Collision Detection in my Space Invaders like game :

```
for(byte k = 0; k < enemies.length; k++) {
    if(shot.x < enemies[k].getTexture().getImageWidth() && shot.x  > enemies[k].pos.x) {
            if(shot.y - 1.2f * frameCount < enemies[k].pos.y && shot.y - 1.2f * frameCount > Main.enemies[k].pos.y - enemies[k].getTexture().getTextureHeight()) {
                    Main.enemies[k].hit = true;
            }
    }
}
```

However, there is one major flaw in this type of collision detection; I can only detect collisions coming form below. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are only getting collisions from the bottom is that
your bounds checking has some errors.
Below I have given a fixed and slightly clearer version,
and I assume that shotWidth and shotHeight can be calculated.
(I have left out the part regarding frameCount, but it should
be possible to edit it in again if needed).

```
final int shotX = shot.x;
final int shotY = shot.y;
final int shotWidth = ?
final int shotHeight = ?
for(byte k = 0; k < enemies.length; k++) {
    final int enemyX = enemies[k].pos.x;
    final int enemyY = enemies[k].pos.y;
    final int enemyWidth = enemies[k].getTexture().getImageWidth();
    final int enemyHeight = enemies[k].getTexture().getImageHeight();

    if(     shotX < enemyX + enemyWidth &&
            shotX + shotWidth < enemyX &&

            shotY < enemyY + enemyHeight &&
            shotY + shotHeight < enemyY) {

        Main.enemies[k].hit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance. I will try this as soon as possible.